# sshd process inoperative

Tags: aix, openssh

I have an AIX server which suddenly stopped servicing SSH connections. When I try to start the service through startsrc -s sshd it says:

```
0513-059 The sshd Subsystem has been started. Subsystem PID is 258300.
```

However, right after issuing the command, the services status shows up as inoperative:

```
 sshd             ssh                           inoperative
```

The init scripts are well located and throw the same result as above.

EDIT: Here's the odmget command output:

```
SRCsubsys:
    subsysname = "sshd"
    synonym = ""
    cmdargs = "-D"
    path = "/usr/sbin/sshd"
    uid = 0
    auditid = 0
    standin = "/dev/console"
    standout = "/dev/console"
    standerr = "/dev/console"
    action = 1
    multi = 0
    contact = 2
    svrkey = 0
    svrmtype = 0
    priority = 20
    signorm = 15
    sigforce = 9
    display = 1
    waittime = 20
    grpname = "ssh"
```

When trying to start the service manually, the following error appears:

```
exec(): 0509-036 Cannot load program /usr/sbin/sshd because of the following errors:
0509-150   Dependent module libz.a(libz.so.1) could not be loaded.
0509-022 Cannot load module libz.a(libz.so.1).
0509-026 System error: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `libz.so.1` is missing on your system.

Comment: Yes, it is. I will restore it to its location to see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

1) enable `LogLevel DEBUG3` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

2) add string `security.debug              /var/log/syslog.security.debug  rotate time 1d files 4` to `/etc/syslog.conf`

3) then

```
# touch /var/log/syslog.security.debug
# stopsrc -s syslogd
# startsrc -s syslogd
# stopsrc -s sshd
# startsrc -s sshd
```

Comment: I tried changing what you said, but It didn't shows any useful logging information. I check the log file after restarting syslog and ssh services but there's no information there.

Comment: Is `/var/log/syslog.security.debug` empty? Does `ps -elf | grep ssh` get something? What `errpt` says?

Comment: As a matter of fact, the file is empty. errpt does not show any sshd-related entries and ps -elf does not show the process running. Thank you.

Comment: Does `/var/adm/ras/syslog.caa` contain some clues? If it doesnt exist touch this file and try to restart sshd.

Comment: Please provide `odmget -q subsysname=sshd SRCsubsys`

Comment: After creating the syslog.caa file, the service restart does not generate any information. I edited the question to include the odmget output.

Comment: Odmget looks good. Try to start sshd manually: '/usr/sbin/sshd -d -e'. What is your oslevel?

Comment: When I issue '/usr/sbin/sshd -d -e' the following error appears:                                                        exec(): 0509-036 Cannot load program /usr/sbin/sshd because of the following errors:
        0509-150   Dependent module libz.a(libz.so.1) could not be loaded.
        0509-022 Cannot load module libz.a(libz.so.1).
        0509-026 System error: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.

Comment: you need some commands to investigate: `ldd /usr/sbin/sshd`, `ls -l /usr/lib/libz.a`, `slpp -w /usr/opt/freeware/lib/libz.a`, `lppchk -m 3 -v rpm.rte`, `lppchk -m 3 -c rpm.rte`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no `libz.a` in `/etc/opt/freeware/lib`.

Use the command and find `libz`:

```
find / -name 'libz*' -exec ls -l {} \;  2>/dev/null
```

After, copy the library to `/opt/freeware/lib/`. Example:

```
cp /opt/freeware/lib/saveoldrpm/oldrpm/lib/libz.a /opt/freeware/lib
startsrc -s sshd
```